# picamera mmal error (One script works vs. another one does not)

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

So I have two version of taking pics with picamera. 
This one works when I run.

```
import cameraTrigger as ct
from picamera import PiCamera
import time

n=1
TOTAL_PICS=30
while n <= TOTAL_PICS:
    img = ct.takePic()
    n+=1
```

cameraTrigger.py

```
import time
import socket
import pickle as p
import numpy as np
import cv2
from picamera import PiCamera
from common import constantSource as cs

camera = PiCamera()
size = cs.getImageSize()
camera.resolution = size
def takePic(path=None):

    if path is not None:
        start = time.time()
        camera.capture(path)
        end = time.time()
        print("Trigger time: " + str(end-start))
        data = None
    elif path is None:
        start = time.time()
        data = np.empty((size[1], size[0], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        camera.capture(data, "bgr")
        end = time.time()
        print("Trigger time: " + str(end-start))
    return data
```

However, this one (an integrated script) does not work. It stops in line 3 (camera = PiCamera()).

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (720,560)
time.sleep(2.0)
n=1
TOTAL_PICS=30
while n <= TOTAL_PICS:
    img = np.empty((560,720,3),dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(img,"bgr")
    n+=1
```

with this error

```
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x10ad0a0 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stereoCalibration_pi.py", line 17, in <module>
    left = PiCamera()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

What is the reason of the error I encounter?? Thank you for your help in advance!!

Comment: The second one presumably takes infinitely many pictures as fast as possible because `n` and `TOTAL_PICS` are never set or changed.

Comment: @Mark Setchell I added n+=1 (since I have that in my original script.) mmal is not coming from the line, it is coming from camera = PiCamera()

Comment: And `TOTAL_PICS`? Did you try printing `n` on each iteration to see if it fails on the first pass or only after a few thousand images?

Comment: TOTAL_PICS is 30, so it iterates 30 times and saves the image by using cv2.imwrite. For the second (not working) script, I even cannot get into the while loop because the erorr occurs before it.

Comment: Ok, where does it get to then? Try copying and pasting the lines into `ipython` one at a time till it fails. I guess `camera.resolution = (720,560)` is wrong as that's the only code that touches the camera.

Comment: Could you elaborate the process of using ipython? I connect to Raspberry Pi via SSH and run the script there. The only way I know is to use Anaconda, but it does not seem to be possible to install it to my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I ssh into the Raspi and run `ipython` and I get an interactive shell. I then type a line of code and see if it works, if it does I copy and paste the line into an editor where I am developing a script so I can save it. It's great because you get any error messages as soon as you type the code. Also, if you type a variable name, or expression, it prints the value without needing a debugging `print` statement. So, if you load an image, or a variable, you can do `fred=7+bill` and then type `fred` and see what it contains. It's very productive.